# How to separate painted texture portions from original mesh. The main goal is for just the symbol I've drawn to have a holdout shader

Tags: rendering, mesh, materials, shaders, texture-painting

I've drawn a symbol on a shield, and for a particular render, I need just the shield (without the symbol) to be visible, with the symbol having an holdout shader.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This can be accomplished with a Mix Shader Node using an image of your symbol (in this example a black'n'white render of Greasepencil Suzanne stands in for that) as the Factor input, the Shader inputs being a Holdout node and a version of your shield texture without the symbol on it.  Remember that the Render Engine must be Cycles, Render Properties > Film > Transparent must be checked, and the render must be saved in a format that can handle transparency.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! And what if I wanted to show just the symbol, with the rest of the surface of the shield being the holdout?

Comment: Flipping the Shader inputs to the Mix Shader node is the easiest way I'd say - in the example above link the Holdout node's output to the bottom Shader input, and the shield's texture (this time the one with the symbol on it) in the top Shader input of the Mix Shader Node.